# Missing Keyword in SQL Code on Foreign Keys unable to create the table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, attributes, foreign-keys

Trying to create a table with an SQL code, but I'm getting an error:

> Missing keyword

in regards to the foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE Staff 
(
    staffID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(50), 
    position VARCHAR(30),
    branchID VARCHAR(5),
    PRIMARY KEY (staffID),
    FOREIGN KEY (branchID) REFERENCES Branch ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike other RDBMS (such as MySQL for example), Oracle does not support the `ON UPDATE` clause in foreign keys. You would just need to remove that part of the declaration.

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE Staff (
    staffID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(50), 
    position VARCHAR(30),
    branchID VARCHAR(5),
    PRIMARY KEY (staffID),
    FOREIGN KEY (branchID) REFERENCES Branch(branchID) --ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dc220dc2faf709630e0454276fbfc03d)**

The logic behind this Oracle behavior is that the referred column is not supposed to change, since it must be `PRIMARY KEY` (or a `UNIQUE` column). I believe that this limitation makes sense... they just don't want to give users enough rope to hang themselves with.

Comment: Thanks so much. Completely makes sense, and can't believed it was this simple. Sorry, i'm pretty new to SQL. But thanks for clarifying it!

Comment: What about cascading deletes? I can see restricting updates for this reason, but not deletes.

Comment: @Omnifarious: yes, `ON DELETE CASCADE` is allowed in Oracle. See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52180).

Comment: @NicoleVelos: Welcome! I can guarantee that most of us once fell in that trap (I, at least, did!).

Comment: @GMB:   So I attempted to create the table but now I have an error stating "the table or view does not exist" - i'm so confused with this now.

Comment: @NicoleVelos: this works fine in the db fiddle that I put in my answer... Just in case: did you create table Branch, which is referred by the foreign key?

Comment: @GMB: yes I made the Branch table already, that on its own created fine but no clue why i'm getting this error instead. :/